# How to add hyperlink to main title of hoverable dropdown menus?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, menu, dropdown

I am working on creating dropdown menus for my eBay listings. I have gotten to a point where I like the functionality of my menus, but want to perfect them. I currently have hoverable dropdown menus. When I hover over a menu, a drop down list is shown from the menu and each title is hyperlinked to its respective page. What I want to do is add a hyperlink to the hoverable title itself. For example, if I hover over the title of the menu, a dropdown list appears. What I would like to do is be able to click on the title of the menu and have it also take me to a specific web page.

I don't have much experience programming CSS. I have been successful in creating menus from researching it on w3schools.com. I have not figured out a way to do this, and haven't had any luck researching it.

```
<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #21205F;
  color: white;
  width: 130px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.325em;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
  margin: 2px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  border-radius: 10px;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #21205F;
  min-width: 150px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #66BD29}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #66BD29;
}
</style>
```

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Menu Title</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="My Link 1">Link 1 Title</a>
  <a href="My Link 2">Link 2 Title</a>
  <a href="My Link 3">Link 3 Title</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope to add an href link to the Menu Title. When clicked on the menu title, I hope that could take the user to a specific link. I hope that I could do it with the code provided, but maybe it would require a complete reconstruction of how I program this menus. I am currently using .dropbtn with .dropdown and .dropdown-content from w3schools.com.

Comment: Could you provide the CSS that goes along with this HTML?

Comment: Yes I just updated it. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add an A tag inside your button.

HTML:

```
<button class="dropbtn">
    <a href="#"> <!––added-->
        Menu Title
    </a>
</button>
```

CSS :

```
.dropbtn>a { /*added*/
    text-decoration: none;
    color: inherit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, easy fix and kept the same styling as before

Comment: Im glad it worked fine! It would be amazing if you could mark one of the answers as "solved the question" by pressing the check icon below the question votes.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace the button tag with an A tag.

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a href="My Top Link" class="dropbtn">Menu Title</a>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="My Link 1">Link 1 Title</a>
  <a href="My Link 2">Link 2 Title</a>
  <a href="My Link 3">Link 3 Title</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, easy fix :)